Finding the parametric representation of a line in P^2
I am trying to parametrize a general line in $\mathbb{P}^2$, that is:
Given a general $\mathbb{P}^2$ line: $ax+by+cz=0$, find $p_0, m$ such that:
$\ell: p_0 + t \cdot m$.
When $a,b,c$ are'nt zero, this task is quite simple, but it gets complicated for me otherwise.
My script is the following:
def line_parameterization(l):
'''
Given a line l in P^2, the function return its parametric representation. 
Returns: a tuple (p0,m) fits to the parametric representation of the line:  p0 + t*m.
'''
a, b, c = l
if a == b == 0:
    if c == 0:
        raise ValueError(f"{l} isn't a line in P^2.")
    m = np.array([0, 1, 0])
else:
    m = np.array([-b, a, 0]) # perpendicular to the normal vector (a, b, c)
    
if a != 0:
    p0 = np.array([-c/a, 0, 1])

elif b != 0: # a == 0
    p0 = np.array([0, -c/b, 1])

else: # a == b == 0,  c != 0
    p0 = np.array([0, 1, 0])
    
return p0, m

But it does'nt seems to give the correct answer I think.
Can someone help please? No need for writing code, just an explanation.

what is space $P^2$?

The projective space 2

A line in ${\Bbb P}^2$ has the same description as a plane in ${\Bbb A}^3$ though the origin. A parametric representation of this plane is given by a point and two linearly independent vectors in the plane. The canonical point to choose is the origin and any two linearly independent $u, v$ satisfying $ax+by+cz=0$ will do, then the parametric representation is $su+tv$. $$(x,y,z)=(su_0+tv_0,su_1+tv_1,su_2+tv_2).$$
Going back we can take the cross product of $u$ and $v$ to get the normal vector: $$(u_2v_1-u_1v_2)x+(-u_2v_0+u_0v_2)y+(u_1v_0-u_0v_1)z=0.$$
So think about the coordinates of ${\Bbb P}^1$ as $(s:t)$ and pick two points $u$ and $v$ in ${\Bbb P}^2$ on the line $ax+by+cz=0$ $$(x:y:z)=(su_0+tv_0:su_1+tv_1:su_2+tv_2).$$
An algorithm: any two lines will intersect, so try the three lines $x=0,y=0,z=0$ and get intersections with $ax+by+cz=0$, i.e. $(0:-c:b),(-c:0:a),(-b:a:0),$ now not all of $a,b,c$ can be $0$ so pick two of the intersection points that are not all zero and use those for $u, v$.
